# How to run a local .rdl report with MVC4 web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS. So far I was able to create a few simple reports an run them locally with Visual Studio and remote database that is also used by my MVC4 web app.

What I am trying to accomplish now is to run the reports locally using my web app - preferably PDF format in a separate browser window. For start, it can be a link or a button running a locally stored report with a single parameter. Can you advise what is the best way to accomplish that and what working example should I search for?

Comment: SO is a technical "How do I solve this particular problem" kinda platform.. you simply have to google your question to get a tonne of info on how to achieve what you want

Comment: I know this question is not precisely technical, but I would not ask it without prior research. Simply, so far I was not able to find an answer using google, even though I spent long hours trying.

Comment: I just did a quick search and found lots of examples of what it sounds like you want to do, including one direct to PDF [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=rdl+report+in+mvc+.net+app&oq=rdl+report+in+mvc+.net+app&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDIzNjZqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)